# no simple group of order $945$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I need to show that there are no simple groups of order $945$.

I've tried the regular method using the Sylow theorems.

$$|G|=945=3^3\cdot5\cdot7 $$

If $G$ is simple then there should be 7 Sylow-3 groups ; 21 Sylow-5 groups and 15  Sylow-7 groups. Even if they would all intersect trivially, there will still be no contradiction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to find a contradiction by assuming $G$ is not simple?

Comment: @Joe, Sorry it was a typing error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If as you say there are 7 Sylow 3-subgroups, then the normalizer $N$ of one of these subgroups has index 7.  If $G$ is simple, then there is an injective permutation representation $G \hookrightarrow S_7$, and so $|G| = 945$ must divide $7!$, but this is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

I think every simple group has even order.

Comment: Every *non-abelian* finite simple group has even order.

Comment: Why does every student first learning group theory seriously make that mistake?Really,I had a fellow graduate student who made that mistake the first time he was TAing the undergraduate abstract algebra course!

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Couldn't that be further specified to „of nonprime order”? Or am I missing something here? I'm not questioning the downvotes (Feit-Thompson is obviously not what this question was asking about...).